# Reverse array order in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

If I have an array

```
>> c = 1:10

c =

 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
```

How do I reverse the last five elements, so that my new array is

```
c =

 1     2     3     4     5     10    9     8     7     6
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 5):

Need to use array merge and flip for subarray

```
A = 1:10
A = [A(1:5),fliplr(A(6:10))]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following code, it uses the increment index `:`

```
d = [c(1:5), c(10:-1:6)]
```